# How to open chrome profile with selenium on start

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have my console app in c# and try to open Chrome browser with my profile.
But when i run the application there isn't any profile authenticated.

I try to set:

```
    chromeOptions.EnableMobileEmulation("Nexus 5");
    chromeOptions.AddArgument("–no-sandbox");
    chromeOptions.AddArguments("-disable-gpu");
    chromeOptions.AddArguments("-disable-dev-shm-usage");

    chromeOptions.AddArguments("-user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\");
```

But not work, open chrome without my account. I must add some argument?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mention like this:

```
# path of the chrome's profile parent directory
chromeOptions.AddArguments(r"user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
# name of the directory
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--profile-directory=Default")
```

Comment: i try with: chromeOptions.AddArguments("-user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Anto\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("--profile-directory=Default");

Comment: but still not work

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: no error, but open chrome without my profile (like incognito)

Comment: Before executing the code close all the chrome browser windows and try.

Comment: And make sure all Chrome.exe and ChromeDriver.exe processes have been killed as well.